# Templated template parameter U<T> does not recognize const qualifier

Tags: c++, templates

I was looking into the following piece of code (no real application, just out of curiosity):

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct MyClass{};

template <template <class> class U, class T>
void foo(std::shared_ptr<U<T>> t){ }

template <class U>
void bar(std::shared_ptr<U> t){ }

int main()
{        
    std::shared_ptr<const MyClass<int>> ptr_to_const;
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass<int>> ptr;

    foo(ptr_to_const); // error
    foo(ptr); // OK

    bar(ptr_to_const); // OK
    bar(ptr); // OK
}
```

However, the compiler fails with

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:17:9: error: could not convert 'ptr_to_const' from 'shared_ptr<MyClass<[...]>>' to 'shared_ptr<MyClass<[...]>>'
   17 |     foo(ptr_to_const); // error
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         |
      |         shared_ptr<MyClass<[...]>>
```

Lived demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/PKhjbT). It seems that the const qualifier is ignored when using a template template parameter as in `foo`. Can someone explain me why this won't compile? As expected, calling `bar` does not cause any problems.

Comment: What should `U` and `T` be deduced to if it were to compile?

Comment: @chris I thought ```U``` would be deduced as ```const MyClass``` and ```T``` as ```int``` such that we have ```const MyClass<T>```, but that seems to incorrect.

Comment: `const` applies to types, not templates is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a failure of template deduction.

There's no combination of `U` and `T` to match `std::shared_ptr<U<T>>` from `std::shared_ptr<const MyClass<int>>`. `const MyClass` isn't a template.

You can overload `foo`

```
template <template <class> class U, class T>
void foo(std::shared_ptr<const U<T>> t){ }

template <template <class> class U, class T>
void foo(std::shared_ptr<volatile U<T>> t){ }

template <template <class> class U, class T>
void foo(std::shared_ptr<const volatile U<T>> t){ }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify, ```MyClass``` itself is a template, but ```const MyClass``` won't be recognized by the compiler as such due to the presence of the const qualifier?

Comment: @StefanKssmr yes. `const MyClass` on it's own isn't a thing